# Paste layer and paste style not available in QGIS

Tags: qgis, copy, paste

Lately I've been encountering a problem with QGIS 3.28.

After copying a layer in the table of contents and right clicking on empty space, I do not have the option to paste the layer. Similarly,  pasting style from one layer to another does not appear as an option. Only paste symbol is available. I am only able to export the style as .qml file and then load it on the other layer from the properties.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, deleting the QGIS files under AppData/Roaming and installing the software in a different folder than Program Files.

Not sure if it's related, I may as well mention it in case it rings a bell to anyone, but I've also had a problem with formatted paste in Microsoft Word. For example, I would copy a table and could not paste it as a table, only as values. Microsoft support told me that it might be other software tampering with the registry. That problem was solved by creating a new Windows profile on my computer, but that doesn't solve the QGIS problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First try a new QGIS profile > https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-profiles/

Comment: tried that too, didn't work

Comment: In the top image, where did you click? Have you tried selecting a layer first?

Comment: copied a layer and then right clicked on empty space on table of contents to paste it. Option to paste is not available.

Comment: For the layer, the `paste` option appears only if a layer is in the clipboard. Try to copy the layer, then paste. If it is not available, open a text editor and paste. See what is there, it should be an xml starting with the `<qlr>` node. Since you say that the clipboard content is modified in another application too, you might have another app (or virus?) that is "touching" (accessing, modifying, locking, whatever) your clipboard

Comment: Seems like nothing is getting to your clipboard. The copy functions just create XML on the clipboard which as @JGH says, can be pasted as text if you desire.